# How to parse Octave/matlab matrix output in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, matlab, octave

Say we have an Octave/Matlab matrix filled with data given to us as string like this:

```
N =

 Columns 1 through 6:

  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000
  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000  2.3423e+008  1.0809e+009  1.6893e+010  6.5398e+008

 Columns 7 through 12:

  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000
  3.3553e+009  6.9347e+010  3.5653e+010  2.7392e+011  2.1380e+008  7.9962e+009

 Columns 13 and 14:

  9.0266e+015  2.6575e+007
  9.0265e+015  1.2970e-008
```

So each Columns would have its list of values (here each Column has `2` yet it can have more rows and we do not know how many, we know totall ammount of columns before we are given that string)

How to parsae such beast into a C# `list<list<double> >` at runtime (from given string)?

Comment: You probably don't want a List<List<float>> but rather a float[][], or even better, a double[][].

Answer (score 1):

You should start by [writing the matrices to a file](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-File-I_002fO.html) (in Octave/Matlab).  These files have a consistent format which allows you to pull data out of them.

And wouldn'cha know it, I have some code lying around that parses Octave matrices into .NET!  Never mind the TODO behind the curtain.  This is part of a bigger class, but that should be most of it; if anything critical looks to be missing, add a comment and I'll dig it up.

```
Dictionary<string, object> variables;

private bool ReadAllVariablesFromDataFile(string[] lines)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < lines.Length)
    {
        string line = lines[i];
        int oldI = i;
        i = ReadSingleVariable(i, lines);
    }

    return true;
}

private static bool IsDefinitionLine(string line)
{
    return (line != null && line.TrimStart().StartsWith("#"));
}

private int ReadSingleVariable(int startIndex, string[] lines)
{
    // TODO: Types other than matrix.
    OctaveVariable variable = new OctaveVariable();

    while (IsDefinitionLine(lines[startIndex]))
    {
        ProcessDefinitionLine(variable, lines[startIndex]);
        startIndex++;
    }

    if (!variable.IsInitialized)
    {
        return startIndex;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < variable.Rows; i++)
    {
        ProcessDataLine(variable, lines[startIndex + i], i);
    }

    this.variables.Add(variable.Name, variable.Value);

    return startIndex + variable.Rows;
}

private static void ProcessDefinitionLine(OctaveVariable variable, string line)
{
    string value = GetLineValue(line);

    switch (GetLineId(line))
    {
        case "name":
            variable.Name = value;
            variable.IsInitialized = true;
            break;
        case "rows":
            variable.Rows = int.Parse(value);
            break;
        case "columns":
            variable.Columns = int.Parse(value);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private static void ProcessDataLine(OctaveVariable variable, string line, int rowIndex)
{
    string[] values = line.Trim().Split(' ');
    double[] row = new double[variable.Columns];

    for (int i = 0; i < variable.Columns; i++)
    {
        variable.Value[rowIndex, i] = double.Parse(values[i]);
    }
}

private static string GetLineId(string line)
{
    return line.Split(':').First().TrimStart('#').Trim().ToLowerInvariant();
}

private static string GetLineValue(string line)
{
    string[] pair = line.Split(':');
    if (pair.Length < 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid def line");
    }

    return pair[1].Trim();
}
```